# Promise returning undefined in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here I was created one loginUser model which simply check if user is exists or not code is working fine but I am facing error in `isValidPassword` it will always false condition even if the email and password is true.

Whenever I try to `console.log(isValidPassword)` then it will return undefined and same case happening with `validStatus`

```
const express=require('express');
const bcrypt=require('bcrypt');
let salt;

const loginUser=async (req,res)=>{
       const {email,password}=req.body;
       try{
              let user=await userModel.findOne({email});
               salt= await bcrypt.genSalt(10);

              if(!user) return res.status(400).json("invalid Username or passowrd");
              
              let validStatus=false;
              let isValidPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password,user.password,(err,result)=>{
                     // console.log(err);
                     console.log(result);
                     if(result) validStatus=true;

              });
              console.log(validStatus);
              
              if(!isValidPassword) return res.status(400).json("invalid Username or passowrd");

              const token=createToken(user._id);
              res.status(200).json({_id:user.id,name:user.name,email,token});
       }
       catch(err)
       {
              console.log(err);
       }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use both a callback and a Promise from `compare`. Simply remove the callback from the `compare` call (see [BCrypt with promises](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#with-promises):

```js
let isValidPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password,user.password)
```

Answer (score 2):

bcrypt.compare already returns a promise so dont pass calback to it